# How to skip domain name verification in OpenSSL?

Tags: openssl

I am using both server and client authentication in OpenSSL.

```
SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER | SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT, NULL);
```

But the client does not usually have valid domain name, so I would like to skip domain name check in the verification process. A tailored verification callback function may do but given my limited knowledge in OpenSSL, I would ask for some help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: According to this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788496/verifying-the-domain-of-a-certificate-in-openssl), domain name checking seems not included by default. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

> How to skip domain name verification in OpenSSL?

There's no need to skip it because its not performed by current OpenSSL implementations. Current implementations include 0.9.8, 1.0.0, and 1.0.1.

However, according to the [OpenSSL Change Log](http://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html), OpenSSL 1.0.2 and 1.1.0 will include hostname verification:

> *) Integrate hostname, email address and IP address checking with
>   certificate
>        verification. New verify options supporting checking in opensl utility.
>        [Steve Henson]
>
> *) Fixes and wildcard matching support to hostname and email
>   checking
>        functions. Add manual page.
>        [Florian Weimer (Red Hat Product Security Team)]
>
> *) New functions to check a hostname email or IP address against a
>        certificate. Add options x509 utility to print results of checks against
>        a certificate.
>        [Steve Henson]

According to the change logs, there's a `-verify_name` option, but I did not see where it was incorporated. `apps.c` appears to responds to `-verify_hostname` switch. But `s_client` does not respond to either switch, so its unclear how hostname checking will be implemented or invoked for a client.